# How to exclude Web.Config in deployment Process through MsDeploy

Tags: asp.net, iis, msbuild, msdeploy

I am using package deployment of web application through MSDeploy.

I don't want to deploy web.config through it.

So how can i skip the config file deployment through ms-deploy.

I am using below Command for deployment.

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package=C:\udeploy\agent\var\work\JenKins\MwApplicationData\MarketWorkFlowWebApp.zip -dest:auto=localhost -setParam:name=%1,value=%2 -enableLink:AppPoolExtension
```

Answer (score 4):

I have done this by including the below in the project file (.csproj) towards the bottom after lines like `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`

```
    <Target Name="CustomExcludeFiles" BeforeTargets="ExcludeFilesFromPackage">
      <ItemGroup>
           <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="web.config"></ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```